SQLServer/VB.Net: SQL Column = Column Does not return all values
I'm in a scenario where I'm not able to create tables(not even temp tables), or stored procedures, and need to create parameterized queries that are completely self-contained and passed entirely to the server through VB.Net. In an effort to do this, I've been doing something along the lines of this to create a pseudo-optional parameter, since I can't establish default parameter values, due to not being able to create these queries as procedures.
SELECT COL1
FROM TABLE
WHERE COL1 = (CASE WHERE @Parameter IS NULL THEN COL1 ELSE @Parameter END)

I've noticed that this has a result I'm not expecting, where ONLY rows with values in COL1 that are not null, are returned. When pulling the raw query syntax being passed to the server, and the parameters being pushed, everything looks to be passing as expected, but the results are illogical.
My ultimate goal here is, to have a parameter that is ultimately one that can be omitted, without having a default value pre-assigned. My goal was to avoid using a bunch of conditional statements and logic to string together a query statement, and instead just have one single statement with optional parameters.
I took this over to SQL Fiddle to give it a test, and got the same results
https://sqlfiddle.com/sql-server/online-compiler?id=0218dbd2-9c5b-4da2-b67b-e01d41eac4e5
CREATE TABLE Test (
  ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
  COL1 INT
);

INSERT INTO Test(COL1) VALUES (1),(0),(Null),(Null),(1)

SELECT * FROM Test;
SELECT * From test where COL1=COL1;

This returns the following Tables:



ID
COL1




1
1


2
0


3
Null


4
Null


5
1






ID
COL1




1
1


2
0


5
1



I would expect COL1=COL1 to return 100% of this data set. It is instead only returning 1, 2, 5 from this example set. Am I missing something fundamental about this?
I've always understood Column=Column to be a method to achieve this, but it seems i'm mistaken.

Thank you @T N
This was the correct answer, not the item flagged as correct or the
'this has already been answered' article that was linked. .
This produces the expected results
CREATE TABLE Test (
  ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
  COL1 INT
);

INSERT INTO Test(COL1) VALUES (1),(0),(Null),(Null),(1);

Declare @Param as int 
set @Param = Null;

Select * 
From test 
where ((@param=Null and Col1 is not distinct from Col1)
       Or (@Param IS NOT NULL AND Col1=@Param))


The expectation is wrong. In all databases, not just SQL Server, a NULL means the value is UNKnown. You can't even compare an UNKnown value to itself. This attempt to create dynamic parameters results in bad performance even if written correctly anyway, eg WHERE (@Parameter1 is null or COL1=@Parameter). Such queries can result in inappropriate execution plans as Catch-all queries explains

If you can't create stored procedures why include the empty parameter at all? When you're generating the query yourself (or even better, let Entity Framework or a SQL builder package do it) you don't have to use any parameters you don't want

Nothing stops you from writing query as dynamic sql though?

The linked duplicate answer is obsolete and slightly off topic. Starting with SQL Server 2022, you can use the (horribly verbose) IS NOT DISTINCT FROM comparison operator. See this updated fiddle.

Switching to entity isn't an option. it's an existing monolithic application that was dumped in my lap. The timeframe I have, and the existing framework won't allow for it. this would be 'throw everything away and start over' territory. the empty parameter is included because in some instances it will be used, and others it will not. This was to avoid creating a convoluted query builder.

Since creating sql "in-line", then simply don't add or having the parmater in the where clause part. I do this all the time, say on a search page in which only 1 out of the 5 combo box selections are selected, and hence I build up a strWhere clause, and use cmdSQL.Paramters("@City", sqldbtype.Nvarchar).Value = my combo box value. Remember, the sql command object does NOT require the sql to have been built or set to add such "optional" parameters to the command object. And you do NOT want to use string concatenation for values, but use @SomeParam for this, hence your sql where clause is dynamic
